# Как правильно дать задание Планировщику заданий Open Server?

Tags: php, cron, openserver, планировщик-задач, автозапуск

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт php по расписанию, чтобы он отрабатывал каждый час.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт успешно запускается в нужное время при такой команде:

```
E:\modules\wget\bin\wget.exe -q --no-cache http://localhost/par.php
```

Проблема в том, что у меня в скрипте сессии, откуда с каждым запуском должна браться определенная информация, поэтому, как мне посоветовали здесь же, нужно скрипт запускать с помощью php.exe.
К сожалению, вот это:

```
E:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.1\php.exe -f --no-cache http://localhost/par.php
```

Не хочет работать.

Попробовал пример из документации по Open Server:

https://ospanel.io/docs/

```
E:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.1\php.exe -c E:\OpenServer\userdata\config\PHP_7.1_php.ini" -q -f E:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\par.php
```

Так тоже не работает. Опытные специалисты, не подскажете, как правильно? Извините за беспокойство и заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: вам, очевидно, нужно копать последний вариант, при этом следить за синтаксисом. кавычка там у вас не в тему несколько. Относительно сессии вам писали, что хранение надо перекинуть куда-нить в файл а не сессию.

Comment: Да, просто интересно реализовать с сессией так, чтобы заработало. Незакрытый гештальт) А так вы правы, лучше сохранять и доставать..

Comment: Это парсер, он должен собрать выдачу поисковика через яндекс xml, а затем закинуть ссылки и заголовки в отчет word. Я пробовал так: E:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.1\php.exe -c E:\OpenServer\userdata\config\PHP_7.1_php.ini" -q -f http://localhost/par.php  Тоже не работает..

Comment: в консоли никакой сессии не будет.

Comment: То есть, никак нельзя запускать через планировщик "как бы через браузер"? Чтобы Session_start() работало?

Comment: @teran
к wget оказывается можно параметр --keep-session-cookies добавить, но не сработало у меня.. может, это не работает именно через планировщик задач...

Comment: там еще есть про save/load cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел спорное решение, связанное с тем, чтобы просто написать в планировщике:

```
explorer http://localhost/par.php
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

При таком задании браузер открывается единожды, затем, каждые 25 минут у него добавляется новая вкладка, запускающая мой скрипт. Сессии сохраняются. Скрипт отрабатывает как надо. Меня с моей задачей устраивает. Не знаю, можно ли другой вариант найти. Сессии же связаны с браузером и любое решение, эмулирующее браузер будет, наверное, более громоздким..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVicg.png